# How to do make Where clues to compare input data with Columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I want to get DATA from mysql TABLE by submit this multiple select value & compare with this columns.

http://prntscr.com/nmsmw1
http://prntscr.com/nmsnts

I followed this , but not working.

```php
$Data=Employee::whereIn('skills', $request->skills)->get();
```

Comment: use `find_in_set` for comma separated column

Comment: Please don't post links to images like that. Upload them to imgur instead (which can easily be done directly through the editor you used to write your question in) so the images can be shown inline.

Comment: Sorry for that , i will follow the standard.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert this sql query into laravel, So you can use FIND_IN_SET() in Laravel like as bellow query.

```php
$data = Employee::whereRaw("find_in_set('".$request->skills."',employees.skills)")->get();
```